# Any alternatives to the Gmail mobile CSS and JavaScript framework?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mobile, mobile-website

Does anyone know what CSS and JavaScript API the Gmail mobile app uses?  It looks very neat and clean from my phone.  Are there any similar frameworks that gives you such a neat and clean look?  I had a look at the jQuery mobile API, also looks good.

Comment: Seems like a no brainer to me, companies like Google have their own internally developed CSS and Javascript api...

Comment: I'm looking for a similar framework for my mobile app.

Comment: This is as close as you're going to find: http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/

Comment: Is built over the Google Closure Library. Check this out https://developers.google.com/closure/library/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google uses their own in-house built Javascript frameworks and CSS.

Comment: It looks really neat and clean.

Comment: Yes, I wish they used it on there desktop sites.  Gmail looks like crap these days on the desktop.